# Finding the probability density function of a function of Y = 4U(1-U)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$U$ is a continuous random variable, uniformly distributed along the interval $(0,1)$. Find the probability density function of $$ Y = 4U(1 - U). $$
I know how to use the Method of Distribution Function and the Change of Variable Method. However, the fact that upon writing $U$ in terms of $Y$ to use I get these results: $$ U = 1/2(1 + \sqrt{1 - y})\qquad
U = 1/2(1 + \sqrt{1 - y}) $$
is really tripping me up. I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: First try plotting $Y$ for $U \in (0,1)$. Things can only become clearer after that...